# Mifare classic - what is the address byte for, and how does it work

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

I've read the spec, and what i understand is:
The address byte should contain the index to a block (so values 0-63 for Mifare 1k)
The address is stored 4 times, in a non-inverse - inverse pattern, @ byte 12 - 15: 
   eg for 255: FF, 00, FF, 00

So my questions are:
How do i retrieve the address? by performing a read, and parsing out byte 12? or is their an APi function that i should be using?

also what is the point of the non-inverse - inverse storage pattern? it implies verification
  - is verification performed when i write an address?
  - what about when i read the address? does it perform verification again? or is the structure a framework for implementing my own?

Finally, can someone give a practical scenario of where they use the address byte?

thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing the address in a so-called "value block" and the block address used with read and write commands.

A value block is just a data block with some specially formatted content. When formatting the content of a data block in such a way, you can use additional commands with it: increment, decrement and transfer. The address byte in a value block can be used for your own book keeping, for example to distinguish between different transactions that have been done.

Retrieving the address byte from a value block is done in the same way that you retrieve the value that is stored: by using the read command.

Answer (score 0):

You retrieve the bytes by reading the trailer sector (last block in the sector) and parsing out the values (optionally validating the bit pattern). You then have the access bits 4 times.

These apply to the 4 blocks of a regular sector (or more blocks for bigger sectors). Access bits for the data blocks is interpreted differently from the trailer block.

This approach makes it (for example) possible to have read-only and read-write blocks in the same sector.